# Checking if a solution exists across two inequalities

Tags: number-theory, inequality

If I have

$ay < x < by$

$cx < y < dx$

With $a,b,c,d$ as known (they are real-valued, can be positive or negative or 0) and $x,y$ unknown, is there a methodical way to see if a solution exists for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I suggest you make a drawing in such cases. That's often the easiest way.

Comment: I am writing a program for this so I would rather do it analytically

Comment: @user2367428 I'd suggest drawing a graph too. Drawing a graph may give you some insight into how to go about finding an analytical solution.

Comment: Drawing doesn't help me figure out an analytical approach. The whole difficulty with this is that both equations depend on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If solution points $(x; y)$ exist, linearly scaled points $(kx; ky)$ must also be solutions, as no inequality is violated by multiplying both sides with the same factor.

Therefore, we can assert an arbitrary non-zero value for $x$ and calculate the corresponding solution interval for $y$. If the interval is empty, no solution exists.

Example:

$x = 1$

$ay < 1 < by$

$c < y < d$

With known values for $a, b, c, d$ we can immediately see if there exists a feasible value interval for $y$. It cannot be more than one interval as the intersection of two intervals is either empty or one uninterrupted interval.